After adding IronPython through NuGet in Jetbrains Rider and launching Unity package cannot be seen neither by Unity nor by Rider
I added IronPython package trough NuGet in Rider. Everything worked fine, however after launching Unity .csproj changes and packages are removed from there. So compile errors appear. How to add packages the right way?
I tried to change some files manually, but it didn't really work. I also tried to copy packages folders to Assets/Packages. It almost worked, but other problems appeared:

I found related problem But it is not suitable for me because I use Rider instead of Visual Studio.
Should I install Visual studio to do the same? :)

So the thing is that Unity updates .csproj files by itself, so adding packages through NuGet apart from unity won't work.
The best way to fix this is to use this github pack
Just use this NuGet version for Unity and everything will work fine.
